# Missing argument 'toptext' for parameter in call

Tags: swift, struct

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct MemeModel{
    var topText:String
    var bottomText:String
    var originalImage:UIImage!
    var memedImage:UIImage
   }

struct MemeCollection{

    func getMemeStorage() ->AppDelegate{
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
        return appDelegate as!AppDelegate
    }

    //get memeModel count number
    func count() ->Int{
        return getMemeStorage().memes.count
    }

    //append meme
    func addMeme(Meme meme:MemeModel){
        print("meme added")
        getMemeStorage().memes.append(meme)
        print(getMemeStorage().memes.count)
    }

    //getMeme
    func getMeme(index:Int)->MemeModel{
        return getMemeStorage().memes[index]
    }

 }
```

When I declare a `MemeModel` in this way in `detailViewcontroller`:

```
var detailmemecontroller = MemeModel()
```

the compiler complains with the following:

> missing argument 'toptext' for paramenter in call.

There is no complaint if I declare a `memeCollection` this way:

```
var memeCollection = Memecollection()
```

What do I need to do?

https://github.com/zetaosun/Udacity_meme

Answer (score 0):

`MemeCollection` has no mandatory variables and `MemeModel` has 4 mandatory variables `topText`, `bottomText` `originalImage` and `memedImage`. So if you add any mandatory variable in `MemeCollection` you will also get the same error there.

To fix the error for `MemeModel`. You have two options.

**Option 1**  Either pass all the mandatory parameters like this.

```
var detailmemecontroller = MemeModel(topText: "", bottomText: "", originalImage: UIImage.init(), memedImage: UIImage.init())
```

**Option 2** Make all variables optionals.

```
struct MemeModel{
    var topText:String?
    var bottomText:String?
    var originalImage:UIImage?
    var memedImage:UIImage?
}
```

Comment: And I declared a MemeCollection in that way: var memeCollection = MemeCollecion(),  there is no error,why?